# Problems using picojpeg on a stm32 board. Unknown cause of error codes 19 and 20

Tags: c, bitmap, embedded, jpeg

Me and my classmates are using picojpeg -> https://github.com/richgel999/picojpeg, to convert an image from a camera to a bitmap to be displayed on a stm32 board.

Does anyone have experience with picojpeg and would be able to explain the error codes 19/20, aka PJPG_NOT_JPEG and PJPG_UNSUPPORTED_MARKER.

I am happy to answer more questions but can't post large chunks of code for academic misconduct reasons.

Comment: Do you run the converter on a target platform, or on a PC? If first, try running it under Visual Studio with the same image binary, and if error persists, you can step through the code. Also, have you tried to open raw binary with a regular image viewer? May be it's missing some headers or just incorrectly received

Comment: We are running it on the stm32 board itself, I'm not sure how to do what your saying but I can look into that thanks.